# Why I can't read session attribute from portlet that is set in AutoLogin class

Tags: session, liferay

I try unsuccessful to access from my portlet the session attribute that I have set during the AutoLogin phase.

Setting attribute in AutoLogin class:

```java
@Override
public String[] login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AutoLoginException {
      request.getSession().setAttribute("My-Attribute-Key", "Hello World");
 ...
}
```

Access attribute from Portlet:

```java
@Override
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        Object attribute = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest).getSession().getAttribute("My-Attribute-Key");
...
}
```

Comment: Because they are different sessions.

Comment: why? has every (tomcat) application own separate session scope?

Comment: Yes, indeed they do! Normally, you can't share session attributes between contexts. Think about it. Each application deployed on tomcat could be a different website. It will be a nightmare if they were all allowed to share the attributes.

Comment: But I believe Liferay has a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Session Sharing](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Session+Sharing) on Liferay Wiki.

Comment: you should post the actual answer/solution, even if by merely copying from the linked page

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba StackOverflow is collaborative. Please edit / suggest an edit if you can, to improve this answer.